# Undefined is not an object error when variable is not found on page

Tags: javascript, html

I am getting an undefined error (see image) for a script I wrote for a load more button. This error is not thrown if I have an html attribute on the page with the class of 'view-more'. How do I handle this error on pages that do not contain a load more button?

```js
(function() {

  //
  // Variables
  //

  var viewToggle = document.getElementsByClassName('view-more')[0];
  var hiddenCard = document.getElementsByClassName('hidden-card')[0];
  var viewMoreButton = '<span class="mx-auto">View more</span> <i class="fe fe-arrow-right"></i>';
  var viewLessButton = '<span class="mx-auto">View less</span> <i class="fe fe-arrow-up"></i>';

  //
  // Functions
  //


  viewToggle.onclick = function() {
    toggleView();
  };

  function toggleView() {
    if (hiddenCard.classList.contains('d-flex')) {
      viewToggle.innerHTML = viewMoreButton;
      hiddenCard.classList.add('conceal');
      hiddenCard.classList.remove('d-flex');
    } else {
      viewToggle.innerHTML = viewLessButton;
      hiddenCard.classList.add('d-flex');
      hiddenCard.classList.remove('conceal');
    }
  }

})();
```

```html
<div class="row justify-content-center pt-6">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-9 col-lg-8 col-xl-7">

    <!-- View More Button -->
    <a href="#!" class="btn btn-block btn-outline-gray-300 d-flex align-items-center view-more">
      <span class="mx-auto">View more</span> <i class="fe fe-arrow-right"></i>
    </a>

  </div>
```

Here is the HTML that it's affecting and if not on the page throws error in console (see attached image)

[image]

Comment: "*How do I handle this error on pages that do not contain a load more button?*" don't run the code in that case?

Comment: It looks like you already know the concept of conditionals (`if`)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define the viewToggle variable, you assume that `document.getElementsByClassName('view-more')` will return an array with at least one element. Hence the `[0]` at the end.

It follows that if there are no elements with that classname, `document.getElementsByClassName('view-more')` will return an empty array or `[]`.

So when you index into that empty array with `document.getElementsByClassName('view-more')[0]` what you're getting back is the first element of an empty array `[]`. Also known as `undefined`.

So `viewToggle = undefined.`

Later on in your code you write `viewToggle.onclick`, but we've already said that viewToggle is undefined! Undefined doesn't have any property called onclick!

And that is why javascript is getting mad. He doesn't like it when we try to grab properties from `undefined`.

One potential fix for this is to use an if statement before trying to access that onclick property.

```
    if (viewToggle) {
      viewToggle.onclick = function() {
        toggleView();
      };
    };
```

By adding this `if` statement, we make sure that we will only attempt to access viewToggle's onclick property if viewToggle does not equal undefined.